# Create two save options after editting

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I want to create two save option button. I have a version tracking option with manual save. I've created one save option where it will save without adding a version. So, for adding a version, I need to click "File > Save As New Version".

For manual save, there is an option where I need to click "Save As New Version".

[image: Save1]

So, I want to add another save button where when users click it, it will save as a new version. So I don't have to click "File > Save As New Version".

[image]

Below is my save without save as new version.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument

    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    vpswd = Inputbox$("Pls input code to save :")

    If vpswd = "o" Then

        uidoc.EditMode = True
'       Call uidoc.FieldSetText("ALStatus" , "Draft")
        Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SaveOptions" , "1")
        Call uidoc.Save
'       uidoc.EditMode = False
        Call uidoc.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

How can achieve to create a LotusScript for "Save As New Version"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NotesUIDocument` class has a `SaveNewVersion` method, so you should be able to copy the code from your existing button then just change this line in the copy:

```
 Call uidoc.Save
```

to this:

```
 Call uidoc.SaveNewVersion
```

It took me about 5 minutes to work this out from looking at the Help included with the Notes client. You should have been able to do the same.